# Execute multiple SQL queries simultaneously via multi threading

Tags: java, multithreading

I am having a bit of trouble. I am trying to multi thread my application where the database is being populated simultaneously from 2 files that are being read. I initially had the application where it would read the file one at a time and populate the database which worked fine. While it was quick, there is always room to make it go quicker.

Code is as follows:

```
package fedMerger;

//PREREQUISITES: ENSURE THE FOLLOWING ARE NOT DISABLED IN SERVICES MANAGEMENT WHEN RUNNING THIS UTILITY:
//SQL SERVER BROWER 
//SQL SERVER 
//SQL SERVER VSS WRITER

//BENCHMARK TEST - 11million merged in 77 minutes.

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

class Merger extends Thread {
    public String mapperValue2="";
    public int i;
    public int records;
    @SuppressWarnings("null")
    public void run() {
        FedMerger merger = new FedMerger();
        try {
            BufferedReader agentFile = new BufferedReader(
                    new FileReader(merger.getDirectory() + merger.getAgentFile()));
            Connection connection = null;
            PreparedStatement statement = null;
            statement = connection.prepareStatement(merger.getQuery());
            for (mapperValue2 = agentFile.readLine(); mapperValue2 != null; mapperValue2 = agentFile.readLine()) {
                i++;
                records++;
                if (!mapperValue2.isEmpty() && mapperValue2.length() > 5) {
                    statement.setString(1, mapperValue2.substring(0, 26));
                    statement.setString(2, mapperValue2.substring(26, mapperValue2.length()));
                    statement.addBatch();
                } else {// ignore blanks or white spaces
                    System.out.println("blank found - skipped");
                }
                if (i == 100000) {// Populating 5000 records at a time
                    System.out.println("executing Agent - " + records + " records...");
                    statement.executeBatch();
                    statement.clearBatch();
                    i = 0;
                }
            }
            statement.executeBatch();
            statement.close();
            agentFile.close();

        } catch (SQLException | FileNotFoundException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}

public class FedMerger {
    private static String directory = "C:\\Users\\xxx\\Desktop\\Files\\";
    public String getDirectory() { return directory; }
    private static String AgentfileName = "file1.txt";
    String getAgentFile() { return AgentfileName; }
    private static String otherFileName = "file2.txt";
    private static String mapperValue = "";
    private static String TimeStampTableName = "TimeStampTable";
    public String getTableName() { return TimeStampTableName;}
    private static String timeStampColumn = "TIMESTAMP";
    String getTimeStampColumnName() { return timeStampColumn; }
    private static String remainingDataColumn = "REMAINING";
    String getRemainingDataColumn() { return remainingDataColumn; }
    private static String user = "sa";
    private static String pass = "uwegudUh4";
    public static String Timestampquery="";
    String getQuery() {return Timestampquery; }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Connection conn = null;
//      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
//      System.out.print("Enter the full directory of where the file is located: ");
//      directory = input.nextLine().trim();
//      System.out.print("Enter The Agent FED File Name (Include extension): ");
//      AgentfileName = input.nextLine().trim();
//      System.out.print("Enter The Mapping FED File Name (Include extension): ");
//      otherFileName = input.nextLine().trim();

        try {// Database setup and file to be read.

            BufferedReader timeStampFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(directory + otherFileName));
            String dbURL = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\\SQLExpress;database=TIMESTAMP_ORGANISER;integratedSecurity=true";
            long timer = System.currentTimeMillis();
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, user, pass);

            if (conn != null) {
                System.out.println("Connecting to SQL Server...");
                System.out.println("Create table & columns...");

                String createTimeStampTable = "CREATE TABLE " + TimeStampTableName + "(" + timeStampColumn
                        + " varchar(max)," + remainingDataColumn + " varchar(max))";
                conn.createStatement().executeUpdate(createTimeStampTable);
                System.out.println("Tables & Columns created - Populating data...");
                int i = 0;
                int records = 0;
                Timestampquery = "INSERT INTO " + TimeStampTableName + "(" + timeStampColumn + ","
                        + remainingDataColumn + ") VALUES (?,?)";

                PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(Timestampquery);
                Merger populateAgents = new Merger();
                populateAgents.run();
                // Dump FED info onto SQL
                for (mapperValue = timeStampFile.readLine(); mapperValue != null; mapperValue = timeStampFile
                        .readLine()) {
                    i++;
                    records++;
                    if (!mapperValue.isEmpty() && mapperValue.length() > 5) {
                        ps.setString(1, mapperValue.substring(0, 26));
                        ps.setString(2, mapperValue.substring(26, mapperValue.length()));
                        ps.addBatch();
                    } else {// ignore blanks or white spaces
                        System.out.println("blank found - skipped");
                    }
                    if (i == 100000) {// Populating 10000 records at a time
                        System.out.println("executing timestamp - " + records + " records...");
                        ps.executeBatch();
                        ps.clearBatch();
                        i = 0;
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("executing " + records + " records...");
                ps.executeBatch();
                ps.clearBatch();
                i = 0;
                // Dump AGENT FED info into same SQL
                System.out.print("Uploaded to database - Working SQL query");
                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(directory + "newfile" + "_MergedFinal.txt"));
                // Organise accordingly
                String retrieveData = "select " + timeStampColumn + "+" + remainingDataColumn + " as Data from "
                        + TimeStampTableName
                        + " order by timestamp, case WHEN remaining LIKE '%agentStateEvent%' THEN -3 "
                        + "WHEN remaining LIKE '%TerminalConnectionCreated%' THEN -2 " + "ELSE -1 END";
                PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(retrieveData);
                ResultSet result = null;
                result = stmt.executeQuery();
                int j = 0;
                String results = "";
                System.out.println("Data organised, ready to output...");
                while (result.next()) {// SQL Query ran - Output data line by
                                        // line
                    j++;
                    System.out.println("outputing data - " + j);
                    results = result.getString("data");
                    writer.write(results + "\r\n");
                    writer.flush();
                }
                writer.write(results + "\r\n");
                writer.flush();
                writer.close();
                System.out.println("Done - View at " + directory + "NewFile_MergedFinal.txt");
                conn.createStatement().executeUpdate("DROP TABLE " + TimeStampTableName);
                conn.close();
                timeStampFile.close();


                System.out
                        .print("Complete - Time taken: " + ((TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(System.currentTimeMillis())
                                - TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(timer))) + " minutes");
            }
        } finally {
            try {
                if (conn != null && !conn.isClosed()) {
                    conn.close();
                }
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                conn.createStatement().executeUpdate("DROP TABLE " + TimeStampTableName);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem seems to occur here:

```
        statement = connection.prepareStatement(merger.getQuery());
```

which throws:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at fedMerger.Merger.run(FedMerger.java:36)
>       at fedMerger.FedMerger.main(FedMerger.java:119)

I am unsure if this due to the fact I have more than 1 prepareStatments in place, one in each class. If that is the case, how do I pass in the existing prepareStatment into other classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your connection is Null when calling  prepare statement.  Create connection first  and then call prepareStatement.

Have a look at example code:http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-create-database.htm

Comment: Ahhh yes i missed this. Thanks :)